# Datawave extract string using regexp

Tags: mule, dataweave

I'm trying to extract a part of a string using a regular expression:

```
\[CODE\] \((.*?)\)
```

Given the string `[CODE] (ABC-212) Rest of the title` this match (https://regexr.com/557qd)

I used this regexp in my current java application, and now I'm trying to transform this on a Mule App.

Reading the documentation I see that I need to use a Transform, so I setup like this:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
vars.subject match(/\[CODE\] \((.*?)\)/)
```

I stored the string on the var called `subject`.

Using that regexp on Mule, do not works.. but in my java application does. What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataWeave doesn't seem to have a global search flag (the g at the end of the original regex). This means the regular expression has to match the entire string. You use the parenthesis to indicate capture groups that will be returned additionally to the matched string.

Script:

```
vars.subject match(/^\[CODE\] \((.*)\).*/)
```

Output:

```
[
  "[CODE] (ABC-212) Rest of the title",
  "ABC-212"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

> Match in DataWeave returns an array that contains the ***entire matching expression***, followed by all of the capture groups that match the provided regex. And in your case "Rest of the title" was not matching as per per Regex provided by you.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json 
var subject="[CODE] (ABC-212) Rest of the title"

---

//Catch here is, Regex should be fully matching as per input,
{
matchesOnly:subject matches /(\[CODE\]) \((.*?)\)[\w\W]*/,
matchOnly: subject match /(\[CODE\]) \((.*?)\)[\w\W]*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is the top question for the Google search "dataweave regex extract", I thought I'd add to this years later after being frustrated as to why my regex wasn't working.

You can use the [`scan`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-scan) function, which unlike `match` does not need to match the entire expression, so you can use the regex you were expecting to work:

```
vars.subject scan(/\[CODE\] \((.*?)\)/)
```

`scan` returns an array of arrays (see the docs page linked above), so in cases like yours where there'll only be one match we can flatten the result:

```
flatten(vars.subject scan(/\[CODE\] \((.*?)\)/))
```

(it might be sensible to guarantee only one match by starting the regex with `^`)

Output:

```
[
  "[CODE] (ABC-212)",
  "ABC-212"
]
```